# Append to List Nested in Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

I am trying to append to lists nested in a dictionary so I can see which letters follow a letter. I have the desired result at the bottom I would like to get. Why is this not matching up?

```
word = 'google'
word_map = {}

word_length = len(word)
last_letter = word_length - 1

for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    if index < last_letter:
        if letter not in word_map.keys():
            word_map[letter] = list(word[index+1])
        if letter in word_map.keys():
            word_map[letter].append(word[index+1])
    if index == last_letter:
        word_map[letter] = None

print word_map

desired_result = {'g':['o', 'l'], 'o':['o', 'g'], 'l':['e'],'e':None}
print desired_result
```

Comment: you have got to learn the `else` clause.

Answer (score 5):

Use the standard library to your advantage:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'google'

d = defaultdict(list)
for l1,l2 in izip_longest(s,s[1:],fillvalue=None):
    d[l1].append(l2)

print d
```

The first trick here is to yield the letters pair-wise (with a `None` at the end).  That's exactly what we do with `izip_longest(s,s[1:],fillvalue=None)`.  From there, it's a simple matter of appending the second letter to the dictionary list which corresponds to the first character.  The defaultdict allows us to avoid all sorts of tests to check if the key is in the dict or not.

Comment: This'd be the way I do it ;)

Comment: @JonClements -- Yeah.  And if `s` is really big and you don't want to copy it to do `s[1:]`, you could probably get away with using `islice` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if letter not in word_map.keys():
   word_map[letter] = list(word[index+1])

# now letter IS in word_map, so this also executes:
if letter in word_map.keys():
    word_map[letter].append(word[index+1])
```

You meant:

```
if letter not in word_map.keys():
   word_map[letter] = list(word[index+1])

else:
   word_map[letter].append(word[index+1])
```

Another thing: what if the last letter also occurs in the middle of the word?